# OffsetDateTime customer parser

Tags: java, offsetdatetime

Hello I try parse String 20110330174824917 to OffsetDateTime using DateTimeFormatter so

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
       // System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("20110330174824917", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS")));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("20110330174824917", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS")));
    }
```

but I get
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20110330174824917' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 8
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)

---

Hey guys it looks like this problem is related with java 8
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085

Thank you all for help

Comment: Well, you are using an `OffsetDateTime`, but both your pattern and your string-to-be-parsed don't have a zone offset. `LocalDateTime` is a better fit in this case.

Comment: By the way, [I cannot reproduce it](https://ideone.com/mpfo5x).

Comment: I try with LocalDateTime but problem still appear

Comment: I edit code in topic maybe it will help to reproduce it

Comment: I have try to your code and it's work perfectly. What is the version of the jdk you use ?

Comment: [I still cannot reproduce it](https://ideone.com/6bfVxL).

Comment: Have you saved and recompiled the file? Is the datetime string mentioned in your post *exactly* the string you used when compiling and running the program? With other words: are there absolutely no invisible (non-printable) characters present in your string?

Answer (score 2):

### [`DateTimeFormatter#withZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-)

Your date-time string does not have timezone information and therefore, in order to parse it into `OffsetDateTime`, you need to pass the timezone information explicitly. You can use `DateTimeFormatter#withZone` to parse the date-time string into `ZonedDateTime` which you can convert to `OffsetDateTime` using [`ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime--).

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "20110330174824917";
        
        // Change the ZoneId as per your requirement e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                                .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        
        OffsetDateTime odt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf)
                                            .toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-03-30T17:48:24.917+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the used `Zone` for the Formatter and concatenate the input string with the correct Zone Offset

```
// note the added Z at the end of the pattern for the offset
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSZ").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("20110330174824917" + "+0000", formatter);
```